# Why doesn't fusion log binding errors?

Tags: asp.net, .net, assemblies, fusion

I have added the following to the registry key Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Fusion:

- EnableLog DWORD 1
- LogFailures DWORD 1

If I start an ASP.NET web site from Visual Studio it throws a Parser Error:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'CMS.Controls, Version=4.1.3518.21577,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=834b12a258f213f9' or
>   one of its dependencies. The located
>   assembly's manifest definition does
>   not match the assembly reference.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Now if I refresh or restart the Assembly Binding Log Viewer it's empty. Shouldn't it log this error?

Only when I add DWORD ForceLog 1 to the registry it logs the error. But then the log fills up with all the successful bindings as well, and since it doesn't sort by name, it's difficult to find the error in the list.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is similar to [How to enable assembly bind failure logging (Fusion) in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net) related to Fusion bind logging

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the fusion log viewer to set those registry keys (fuslogvw.exe - I think you're using that already from the sounds of things) - I've also found in the past that the best way of getting information out is to configure it so that logs are stored to a custom path - to do this:

- Open fuslogvw.exe
- Click **settings**
- Check the **Enable custom log path** checkbox
- Enter the location you want logs to get written to, e.g. c:\FusionLogs (**Important:** make sure that you have actually created this folder in the file system.)
- Make sure that the right level of logging is on (I sometimes just select **Log all binds to disk** just to make sure things are working right)
- Click **OK**
- Set the log location option to **Custom**

Remember to turn of logging off once you're done!